# my mySQL query takes too much time (about 12 seconds) - any suggestions

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, query-performance, correlated-subquery

I have a problem with a mySQL query, as it takes too much times (about 12 seconds) the table have about 70,000  records

here is my query:

```
SELECT  DATE(`orders`.`date`) AS `dater`,
        COUNT(*) AS `amount`,
        ( SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `payment`
              WHERE DATE(`dater`)=DATE(`payment`.`posted_date`)
        ) AS `charge`
    FROM `orders`
    GROUP BY `dater`
    ORDER BY `dater` DESC
    LIMIT 0,10
```

As you can see there is 2 tables
1. table: orders
it is the orders tables here we have 1 main column: date (we need here to count the orders per day)

sample:

```
--------------------
date        | id
--------------------
01-01-2017  | 1
--------------------
01-01-2017  | 2
--------------------
01-02-2017  | 3
--------------------
```

2. table: payment:
   it is the payments table here we have 2 main columns: posted_date, amount (we need here to get the sum of amount field for the every day)

sample:

```
--------------------
posted_date | amount
--------------------
01-01-2017  | 100
--------------------
01-01-2017  | 50
--------------------
01-02-2017  | 200
--------------------
```

so at end the results should be [date, amount, charge]

sure in less time, as it is impossible to go with this 12 seconds :D

I see that the problem is on this internal SELECT:

```
(SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `payment`
    WHERE DATE(`dater`)=DATE(`payment`.`posted_date`)
) AS `charge`
```

any suggestion of how can I avoid making SELECT inside the SELECT query?

Comment: Perhaps consider indexing your data tables

Comment: That `COUNT(*)` is an issue also. It has to go through your entire table and if it's not properly indexed, it makes it even worse.

Comment: Can we see your schema?

Comment: Pls share the results of the explain and all indexes you have on the 2 tables.

Comment: the result will be 3 columns: [dater, amount, charge]

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a correlated subquery. MySQL's query planner handles those in a naive way, to put it politely.

Refactor your query to use a join instead.  Your correlated subquery would look like this as a joinable query.

```
           SELECT SUM(amount) charge,
                  DATE(posted_date) posted_date
             FROM payment
            GROUP BY DATE(posted_date)
```

This gets one row per day from the payment table.

Next, you need to get a similar sort of result from your orders table.

```
         SELECT DATE(date) AS dater,
                COUNT(*) AS amount
           FROM orders
          GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Then, join those two together

```
SELECT a.dater, a.amount, b.charge
  FROM (
         SELECT DATE(date) AS dater,
                COUNT(*) AS amount
           FROM orders
          GROUP BY DATE(date)
       ) a
  LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT SUM(amount) charge,
                  DATE(posted_date) posted_date
             FROM payment
            GROUP BY DATE(posted_date)
       ) b ON a.dater = b.posted_date
 ORDER BY a.dater DESC
 LIMIT 0,10
```

It's necessary to join two subqueries here, because you need two aggregates by date for the join to work.

Comment: This can be sped up some by adding `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 10` in each subquery.  The  amount of the speed up depends _quadratically_ on the number of dates.